# For your account security, logging into Facebook from an embedded browser is disabled. Download and log into the Facebook app on your device

Tags: android, facebook

The Facebook login feature suddenly stopped working on my Android app. I am getting this error message:

> For your account security, logging into Facebook from an embedded
> browser is disabled. To continue, download and log into the Facebook
> app on your device and try again.

[image]

In my `build.gradle`, this is what I have for Facebook:

`implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.1'`

Is the Facebook SDK version the issue? From what I read in the message, users now have to install the Facebook app on the device and not login from a web browser on the phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's expected behaviour - it was deprecated last year according to [this](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2021/06/28/deprecating-support-fb-login-authentication-android-embedded-browsers/?locale=en_US) article. You should [migrate](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/deprecating-webviews) your app to CustomTabs.

> Beginning October 5, 2021, Facebook Login will no longer support using Android embedded browsers (WebViews) for logging in users.

Comment: this is for android, what is to be done for react native?